# How can i get refresh time from html input box and refresh it with that parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

i want use auto refresh page in html code,i use this html code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
```

every thing is ok,but i want user enter number into the this html input box:

```
<input type="text" ><br>
```

and refresh time time set with up enter number,for more explain,user enter 10 and page refresh every 10 second.how can i solve that?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested.

To get all meta tags

```
var metaTags = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
```

To loop over them to find the right one

```
for (var i = 0; i < metaTags.length; i++) {
  if (metaTags[i].getAttribute("http-equiv") === "refresh") {
  }
}
```

And finally to change refresh interval (inside the if)

```
metaTags[i].setAttribute("content", yourValue);
```

Hope this works.